# How to mock Func<Type, IHandler>?

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I have a service method as below. I am trying to mock in test method

```
public class A
{
    private readonly IHandler createDeviceContentStatus;
    private readonly IHandler updateDeviceContentStatus;
    public A(Func<Type, IHandler> handlerFactory)
    {
        this.createDeviceContentStatus = handlerFactory(typeof(CreateDCS));
        this.updateDeviceContentStatus = 
            handlerFactory(typeof(UpdateDeviceContentStatus));
    }
}
```

How can I create Mock for class `A` constructor in test method?

Any leads are appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to add an overloaded constructor:

```
public class A
{
    private readonly IHandler createDeviceContentStatus;
    private readonly IHandler updateDeviceContentStatus;
    public A(Func<Type, IHandler> handlerFactory)
      : this(handlerFactory(typeof(CreateDCS)), handlerFactory(typeof(UpdateDeviceContentStatus)))
    {
    }
    public A(IHandler createDeviceContentStatus, IHandler updateDeviceContentStatus)
    {
        this.createDeviceContentStatus = createDeviceContentStatus;
        this.updateDeviceContentStatus = updateDeviceContentStatus;
    }
}
```

Then mocking will be quite easy:

```
Mock<IHandler> createDeviceMock = new Mock<IHandler>();
Mock<IHandler> updateDeviceMock = new Mock<IHandler>();
// setup the mocks
A a = new A(createDeviceMock.Object, updateDeviceMock.Object);
```

If you don't want to create this constructor, create a lambda that returns your mocks:

```
Mock<IHandler> createDeviceMock = new Mock<IHandler>();
Mock<IHandler> updateDeviceMock = new Mock<IHandler>();
// setup the mocks
Func<Type,IHandler> factory = (t) =>
{
if(t == typeof(CreateDCS)) return createDeviceMock.Object;
if(t == typeof(UpdateDeviceContentStatus)) return updateDeviceMock.Object;
throw new ArgumentException();
};
A a = new A(factory);
```